# Firebase create user with email, password, display name and photo url

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to Firebase site, I am using this code to create a new user:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {});
```

How can I add display name and photo url to Auth when creating the new user?

This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/protocol_f_i_r_user_info-p#a604fe5f388e94434558e1f8ba9d8e9f4) shows the supported user data returned from an identity provider in Auth.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can update your profile  with `FIRUserProfileChangeRequest` class .. check [this Doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
   if let user = user {
      let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()

      changeRequest.displayName = "Jane Q. User"
      changeRequest.photoURL =
          NSURL(string: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg")
      changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion { error in
        if let error = error {
          // An error happened.
        } else {
          // Profile updated.
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There is no way we can add display name and photourl at the same time when creating a new user with email and password?

Comment: no .... there is no other way ... after creation you need to update your user profile

Comment: I am able to get the displayName and photoUrl from code now. These two fields are not shown in Firebase Auth console. Is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 5):

I think this should solve it for you, let me know if you need anything else. or have any further questions on this matter.

```
    func handleSignUp() {
    guard let userName = userNameTF.text else { return }
    guard let email = emailTF.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTF.text else { return }
    guard let image = profileImage.image else { return }

    continueButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "inactiveButtonBG"), for: .normal)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {
                print("User created!")
                self.uploadProfileImage(image: image) { url in

                    if url != nil {
                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        changeRequest?.displayName = userName
                        changeRequest?.photoURL = url

                        changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
                            if error == nil {
                                self.saveProfile(username: userName, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                    if success {
                                        print("Success upload of profile image")
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    }
                                }
                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            } else {
                                guard let message = error?.localizedDescription else { return }
                                self.userAlert(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.userAlert(message: "Unable to load profile image to Firebase Storage.")
                    }
                }

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                guard let message = error?.localizedDescription else { return }
                self.userAlert(message: message)
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change/add the display name:

`user!.createProfileChangeRequest().displayName = "Your name"`

To change/add photoURL

`user!.createProfileChangeRequest().photoURL = URL(string: "image url")`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can solve your problem as follow.

1) Create a user using following statement.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {});
```

2) success of above statement Please **authenticate** this user as follow.

```
     self.rootRef.authUser(email, password)
 // USER_ID = Here you get user_ID
```

3) Success of above function set user name and profile picture to user as follow.

```
  usersRef.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock:
```

-Here userRef contain your userDetails/USER_ID

Might be work for you.
i have code but work for older firebase version so not work for you otherwise i had share with you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean adding display name and photo url to Firebase Database after Auth. This is pretty much what I do all on same registration.

```
   if let email = emailField.text where email != "", let pwd = passwordField.text where pwd != ""{

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: pwd, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("DEVELOPER: Unable to authenticate with Firebase using email")
            }else {
                print("DEVELOPER: Successfully authenticated with Firebase using email")
                if let user = user {
                    let userData = ["provider": user.providerID, "userName": "\(user.displayName)", "profileImg": "\(user.photoURL)"]
                    self.completeMySignIn(user.uid, userData: userData)
                }
            }
        })

     } else {
       // Email and Password where not filled in
    }
}
```

Now adding your profile image and users username in DB here

```
func completeMySignIn(id: String, userData: Dictionary<String, String>){
    {YourFirebaseUserURL}.updateChildValues(userData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) in [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) exactly for your purpose, i.e. to fill up other user properties as the user is created:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Put this code block in your Firebase Function:
admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password,
        displayName: `${fname} ${lname}`,
        disabled: false
    })
```

But creating user with Firebase Admin SDK may give you **problem in sending email verification** because the promise does not return the `User` object that has the `sendEmailVerification()` method. You may eventually need to use the Firebase client API (as shown in your own code) to create the user and [update the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) before sending the email verification:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

It make sense to update the `displayName` before sending email verification so that the Firebase email template will greet the new user with proper name rather than just **Hello** (sounds like a spam) when the `displayName` is not set.