# How to add user's display name when creating user with email and password using Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to add a user's display name when creating user using the     `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method with Firebase on Android.

When I use the following code to update the user's profile I get an exception like so: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]`

**`Task` does not complete successfully**

**The `displayName` variable is also empty.**

**To code is:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;
private Dialog dialog;
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get FireBase FireBaseAuth instance
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String displayName = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
    textView.setText(displayName);
    Log.i(TAG, "Display name = " + displayName);


    if (user.getDisplayName() == null) {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_user_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Update your profile...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        EditText txtName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtName_user_dialog);
        final String name = txtName.getText().toString().trim();

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate_user_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(name)
                        .build();

                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your profile has been updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Profile has been updated.");
                                } else
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Profile has not been updated. " + task.getResult());
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
}
```

**What I ultimately want to accomplish is to add a user display name when creating the user.**

Comment: You can't add the username when creating the user but you can send a profile change request right after creating the user. See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389341/firebase-create-user-with-email-password-display-name-and-photo-url for an example.